# What's the proper way to refer to the form of a word that's improperly punctuated?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, conjunctions, possessives, greengrocers-apostrophe

**Example sentence:**

> The Adventure's of Huckleberry Finn

---

**My dilemma:**

I would like to convey to the writer of the example sentence that the word *Adventure's*, in its current ***_*____** form, is grammatically incorrect (as opposed to its should-be plural form).

At first I started to use the word *possessive* to describe the form, but then I started thinking¹ that maybe, in the writer's mind, the word was in fact not written to represent possession but rather as a contraction of the words *Adventure* and *is*. In the latter case, I believe using the word *contractional* would be more appropriate than using the word *possessive* but since I don't know what the writer was (hypothetically) thinking when they wrote the word, I don't know which adjective to choose, if either.

I realize that chances are the writer just accidentally added an apostrophe where they shouldn't have, but that's neither here nor there.

---

**My question:**

What's the best word to use to describe the current, incorrect form of the word *Adventures* as described above? Is there an all-encompassing word that would be a better fit than the words *possessive*, *contractional*, or a combination thereof?

Thanks!

*¹ Yes, it hurt. ;)*

Comment: Note: _And_ is a conjunction. _Adventure's_ is a contraction.

Comment: Good call. Figures, since this is my first post on the English Language site. ;) Question updated. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apostrophize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apostrophize) - punctuate (a word) with an apostrophe

> I would like to convey to the writer of the example sentence that the
>   word Adventure's, in its current **apostrophized** form, is grammatically
>   incorrect (as opposed to its should-be plural form).

Answer (score 0):

**Misspelled.**  The plural suffix *-s* isn't usually spelled with an apostrophe in this context.

Punctuation punctuates.  It separates.  It shows relationships between units of speech in written form.  The periods in-between these sentences punctuate, and so does the comma in the middle of this sentence.  The apostrophe in *The Adventure's of Huckleberry Finn* does no such thing.

For elaboration on this point, please see Geoffrey Pullum's [*Being an Apostrophe*](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/03/22/being-an-apostrophe/) at Lingua Franca.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to this part of Stack Exchange so I apologize if this sounds ignorant, but are you saying that the answer to _What's the best word to use to describe the current, incorrect form of the word Adventures as described above?_ is _Misspelling_? Or did I misinterpret your answer?

Comment: Yes.  I think that *adventures* is the commonly accepted spelling, and *adventure's* is an alternate way of spelling the word which is not commonly accepted.  As Geoff Pullum says in the link I gave above: "The apostrophe is **not** a punctuation mark. It doesn’t punctuate. Punctuation marks are placed between units (sentences, clauses, phrases, words, morphemes) to signal structure, boundaries, or pauses. The apostrophe appears within words. It’s a 27th letter of the alphabet. This issue concerns **spelling**."

Comment: I think we might say Pullum is ... um ... **unconventional,** as [one of the comments](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/03/22/being-an-apostrophe/#comment-838237313) illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **grammatical error** if the writer of the phrase wouldn't be able to percieve the problem if re-reading it, a **spelling mistake** if it was merely a careless oversight.

In other words, the kind of mistake it was depends on the cognitive state of the writer at the time of the mistake.

As regards your question of how to describe what is going on, the problem is that the possessive (or genitive) singular of the noun has been substituted for the nominative (or basic) plural, and that the distinction is difficult to maintain because the two forms are homophones.  This description is true whether the error was in grammar or in spelling.